# How to concatenate strings in excel?

Tags: vba

How to concatenate strings from a1 util a5 into a new string such as the following.

[image]

```
b1= “a1”,”a2”,”a3”,”a4”,”a5”
```

I knew that method

```
=CONCATENATE(""""&A1&""","""&A2&""","""&A3&""","""&A4&""","""&A5&"""")
```

It is not right way,how about the a column contains 100 strings?

```
 =CONCATENATE(""""&A1&""","""&A2&""","""&A3&""",,omit the same expression,,"""&A100&"""")
```

It is totally un-acceptable.

Comment: i hope you google before asking questions... if you type "concatenate in excel" you will see your answer

Comment: It's usually a good idea to type the title of your question in Google first, typically it will yield a result.

Comment: A sample expression would be: `=CONCATENATE("“"; A1; "”, “"; A2; "”")`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

```
=CONCATENATE(""""&A1&""","""&A2&""","""&A3&""","""&A4&""","""&A5&"""")
```

Since your strings to concatenate are enclosed in quotation marks, use 2 additional quotation marks within the surrounding quotation marks to represent a quotation mark in our result as follows:

```
""""
```

Comment: Unless you're prepared to write up a short description of what the solution is, and only then linking to the documentation, this is a comment at best.

Comment: I'm sorry for that, thank you for warn me about this.

Comment: You can easily salvage this by just typing up a short answer on how to actually concatenate the strings. Then I would remove my comments as well. Here's the expression to handle the first two: `=CONCATENATE(""""; A1; """, """; A2; """")`. The quotes inside the strings must be doubled up to get 1 instead of ending the string, that's why `""""` is the string that contains one quote, the two outer quotes delimits the string and the two inside is the doubled up syntax to get one set of quotes.

Comment: Or `=CONCATENATE("“"; A1; "”, “"; A2; "”")` if he wants the special quotes he's using in his question.